# set background of panel/div inside repeater programatically

Tags: c#, repeater

i have a repeater like this:

```
        <asp:Panel runat="server"  ID="panel1" style="width: 105mm; height: 73mm;>
            <div class="tiles" style="float: right; width: 100px"></div>
            <div class="tiles" style="float: right; width: 100%;text-align:center;padding-top:20px;">
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "image") %>
            </div>
            <div class="tiles" style="padding: 0 20px 0 0;width:93%;text-align:center">
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name") %><br />
            </div>
            <div class="tiles" style="padding: 0 20px 0 0;text-align:center">
                <img src="../pics/sallogo.png" />
            </div>
            <div class="tiles" style="padding: 0 20px 0 0;text-align:center">
                  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Family") %><br />
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
      </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:Repeater>
```

and i need set panel background in code behind,
i,m using this C# code for repeater which if j==0 then set background to a specific image else set to another image:

```
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(helper.conn);
        SqlCommand com1 = new SqlCommand("select id,name,guest  from Person where Id='1', con);
        DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(com1);
        da1.Fill(ds1);
        con.Open();
        com1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //gdvusers.DataSource = ds1;
        //gdvusers.DataBind();
        con.Close();

        rpt_print.DataSource = ToList(ds1.Tables[0]);
        rpt_print.DataBind();
    }

    private List<Person> ToList(DataTable table)
    {
        var categoryList = new List<Person>(table.Rows.Count);
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {


                var values = row.ItemArray;
                String i = values[2].ToString();
                int end = Int32.Parse(i);
                for (int j = 0; j< end+1; j++)
                {

                var category = new Person()
                {
                    Id = long.Parse(values[0].ToString()),// values[0],
                    Name = j == 0 ? "نیکوکار محترم "+values[1].ToString() :"مهمان نیکوکار محترم "+ values[1].ToString(),
                  //  Mobile = values[4].ToString(),
                   // UserId = int.Parse(values[6] != null ? values[6].ToString() : "0"),// values[0],
                    image = j==0?createbarcode(values[0].ToString()):createbarcode(9999+values[0].ToString()),
                    Family = j == 0 ? "تعداد مهمان شما : " + values[2].ToString() : " ",
                };
                categoryList.Add(category);
            }
        }
            return categoryList.ToList();

    }
```

and this code for person class that used before:

```
public class Person
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Family { get; set; }

    public string Meli { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> regdate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: A good place to start would be wiring an event handler to the ItemDataBound event.

Comment: i didn't understand,please write code,

Comment: I'm not here to write your code for you, but if you want an example then you can consult MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't suggest using the horrid ItemDataBound event as some suggest. Gets very ugly. You seem to be setting the 'image' property on your Person type so you can output that in your styles for the Panel using databinding syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the `ItemDataBound` event.

WebForm (aspx)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
            // Your other code here
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Code Behind (cs):

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var panel = (Panel) e.Item.FindControl("Panel1");

        if (true /*Condition for setting panel background color*/)
        {
            panel.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```